# Instagram API returns wrong results for tag media

Tags: instagram

I've noticed something weird and I was thinking that maybe I'm missing something. I noticed that if you use the tag/tagname/media/recent endpoint a lot of the result show they contain the given tag. However if you actually open the url and you see that they either lack that tag or the photo doesn't have any tags at all. Then when doublechecking by querying by specific media id the results are the same. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint returns media where the tag is also in any of the comments. The tag you were searching for might be assigned in any of the comments for that media. I don't believe that all comments are returned for each image in this endpoint, so it might be assigned to a comment that you don't see in your results.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but for some random tags and images I checked manually by opening the media URL. For some there were no comments and no hashtags in the caption even. I'll try to look for a propper example and I'll post it here.